# How to fix this in Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am buildning an android app and i get that error:

```
    "Error:(61, 50) error: incompatible types: ActivityMain cannot be converted to AppCompatActivity"
```

I searched Internet for a solution of this problem but didn't find any fix

that is my code:

```
    mAdapter = new AdapterCategory(getContext(), new ArrayList<Category>());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    // on item list clicked
    mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterCategory.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View v, Category obj, int position) {
            ActivityCategoryDetails.navigate(getClass(), v.findViewById(R.id.lyt_parent), obj);
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is the type of your ActivityMain?

Comment: FragmentActivity

Comment: AppCompatActivity is a FragmentActivity so you can not upcast. Check https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html. Hope it helps.

Comment: can you tell me how to fix it ?

Comment: Can you put all your Code here? Including the  adaptar code

Comment: Which is the line of the error, can you show the called method?

Comment: Please provide a complete example of your code. You should be sure to put all code inside a method inside a class, similar to how it is in your actual code. Also show your activity class...for now we just need the class declaration `public class MainActivity extends ???`. **Note that I am not asking for all of the code for your entire app.** I am only asking you to post code which I can copy and compile myself without getting extra errors about a missing class and code outside of a method.

Comment: Also, which line causes the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a minimum API level of 15, you'd want to use AppCompatActivity.
You can use this AppCompatActivity as your Main Activity, which can be used to launch Fragments. So your MainActivity would look like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ....
    ....
}
```

To use the AppCompatActivity, make sure you have the Google Support Library downloaded (you can check this in your Tools -> Android -> SDK manager). Then just include the gradle dependency in your app's gradle.build file:

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22:2.0'